# try to use LabVIEW func in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, labview

I try to include LabVIEW function into my visual C++ project via DLL. In the dll there is just one function: `void __cdecl imgpro(uintptr_t *ImageOut3, LVBoolean *BL, LVBoolean *R, 
   LVBoolean *L, LVBoolean *BR);`

This function process frames from a camera in LabVIEW.
in visual C++ . I take img,a,b,c,d out from the function.
but there is 1 error at `void __cdecl imgpro(&img,&a,&b,&c,&d); "error: incomplete type is not allowed"` although I think I have provided the function with all parameters and the syntax is ok.

```
#include "SharedLib.h"
#include <extcode.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
LVBoolean a,b,c,d;
uintptr_t img;
void __cdecl imgpro(&img,&a,&b,&c,&d);



system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `void __cdecl imgpro(&img,&a,&b,&c,&d);`
Seeing the word "void" there suprises me.  It looks like you're trying  to declare a function.  What happens if you remove that and just try to call the function?

Comment: oh,thanks, that's my silly fault!.., i get around all errors now except the combination fault: error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file, cannot read at 0x13A    ...actually i am following this link to get it work: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/70995EC2CA1B523386256DD4004F3DE6